# libGDX: How to disable the color on SpriteBatch?

Tags: java, colors, libgdx, spritebatch

With some assets, I'm trying to implement is so that I have a grayscale image, and use the [`Batch#setColor`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html#setColor-float-float-float-float-) method to paint over it programmatically.

However, can [`Batch#setColor`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html#setColor-float-float-float-float-) be disabled afterwards for rendering of the rest of the assets? I only want certain assets to render with the colored overlaid, not everything else as well.

I'm failing to see how to disable it, but I assume there must be a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch's set color is multiplied by the color of the sprite, so to "disable" it, set it to white.

```
batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```